# Attempting to encrypt information before adding it to a pickled dictionary

Tags: python, encryption, pickle

I am currently attempting to save encrypted information in a dictionary in a pickle file, that can then be accessed, decrypted and searched through later on in the code.

I have created a function to encrypt, and then dump the information in a dictionary in my pickle file. But I am getting errors saying that the argument must be a string instead of bytes. I have tried to convert it, but I continue to get the error message regardless of what I have tried.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
password_dictionary = {}
pickle.dump(password_dictionary, open("dictionary.pkl", 'wb'))
dictionary = "dictionary.pkl"

def encrypt_and_dump(username, password):
    f=Fernet(key)
    user_pass = (username + password)
    b_user_pass = user_pass.encode()
    encrypted_user_pass = f.encrypt(b_user_pass)
    d_encrypted_user_pass = str(encrypted_user_pass)
    with open(dictionary, 'a+') as f:
        a = {site:[d_encrypted_user_pass]}
        pickle.dump(a,f)
```

The error message

[image: The error messages coming up at the moment are]

Comment: Please include the error message and the stack trace.  Also, it is unclear what exactly you think your file is going to contain when your done.  You can't dump a dictionary by writing out one element at a time to a file.

Comment: I have just added those to the question. 
I see, I was hoping to create a dictionary on an external file for login credentials. That way later on in the code the file could be searched for the appropriate values, decrypted, and shown on the screen
I was attempting to add a new item to the dictionary with this function. I'm quite new to python, so am certainly not familiar with the ins and the outs of the best practises/methods.

Comment: And what is `site`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file in text mode "a+". Pickle wants to write bytes, but `write()` accepts `str`.

So if you open the file with **binary mode "ab+"**, everything should work:

```
with open(dictionary, 'ab+') as f:
        a = {site:[d_encrypted_user_pass]}
        pickle.dump(a,f)
```